# Creating a dictionary by for loop (?)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have to create a big dictionary for my measurement data.
My (simplified) code looks like this so far:

```py
i = 0  

for i in range(len(station_data_files_pandas)):  # range(0, 299)
    station_data_f_pandas = station_data_files_pandas[i]
    station_id = str(int(station_data_f_pandas["STATIONS_ID"][0]))
    Y_RR = station_data_f_pandas["MO_RR"].resample("A").apply(very_sum)

    # creating the dictionary layer for the anual data in this dictionary
    anual_data = {
            "Y_RR" : Y_RR
            }
    # creating the dictionary layer for the montly data in this dictionary
    montly_data = {
            "MO_RR"    
            }
    # creating the dictionary layer for every station. Everystation has montly and anual data
    station = {
            "montly_data" : montly_data,
            "anual_data" : anual_data
            }
    # creating the dictionary layer where the staiondata can get called by station id
    station_data_dic = {
            station_id : station
            }
    # creating the final layer of the dictionary
    station_data_dictionary = {
            "station_data": station_data_dic
            }
```

This is the output:

```
station_data_dictionary
Out[387]: 
{'station_data': {'4706': {'montly_data': {'MO_RR'},   # "4706" is the id from the last element in station_data_files_pandas
   'anual_data': {'Y_RR': YearMonth
           # YearMonth is the index...
           # I actually wanted the Index just to show yyyy-mm ...
    1981-12-31    1164.3
    1982-12-31     852.4
    1983-12-31     826.5
    1984-12-31     798.8
    1985-12-31       NaN
    1986-12-31       NaN
    1987-12-31       NaN
    1988-12-31       NaN
    1989-12-31       NaN
    1990-12-31    1101.1
    1991-12-31     892.4
    1992-12-31     802.1
    1993-12-31     873.5
    1994-12-31     842.7
    1995-12-31     962.0
    1996-12-31       NaN
    1997-12-31     927.9
    1998-12-31       NaN
    1999-12-31       NaN
    2000-12-31     997.8
    2001-12-31     986.3
    2002-12-31    1117.6
    2003-12-31     690.8
    2004-12-31       NaN
    2005-12-31       NaN
    2006-12-31       NaN
    2007-12-31       NaN
    2008-12-31       NaN
    2009-12-31       NaN
    2010-12-31       NaN
    Freq: A-DEC, Name: MO_RR, dtype: float64}}}}
```

As you see my output consist just of one "sheet". Expected would be 300 sheets.

I assume my code overwrites the data as it loops through, so that at the end my output is just one sheet made from the last element in station_data_files_pandas. How can I fix this? Is my approach maybe entirely wrong?...

When it is ready, it has to look like:

```
station_data_dictionary["station_data"]["403"]["anual_data"]["Y_RR"]
station_data_dictionary["station_data"]["573"]["anual_data"]["Y_RR"]
station_data_dictionary["station_data"]["96"]["anual_data"]["Y_RR"]
```

...and so on.

As you see, the only thing, that I am allowed to change, as I call different things in my dictionary, is my station_id.

Note: There is one question with the exact same title, but it was not helpful to me at all...

Comment: Create the `station_data_dictionary` outside of the `for` loop, then just add the entries inside the loop.

Comment: @Seb thank you for your answer. I tryed this allready, but I was not succsesful. Can you show me how to add the entries inside the loop?

Comment: Have you tried `station_data_files_pandas.to_dict()` or `station_data_files_pandas.to_json()`?  I don't know what the original data looks like, so those functions might not be relevant.

Comment: @MarkMoretto Thank you for your answer. station_data_files_pandas is a list of pandas dataframes. When you call station_data_files_pandas[0] you get a single pandas dataframe.. hmmm thank you for your suggestion, but I think, I can't use a shourt cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this as I don't have your data, but this should produce your required dictionary. The only changes are at the top and bottom:

```py
station_data_dictionary = {
    "station_data": {}
}

for i in range(len(station_data_files_pandas)):  # range(0, 299)

    station_data_f_pandas = station_data_files_pandas[i]

    station_id = str(int(station_data_f_pandas["STATIONS_ID"][0]))

    Y_RR = station_data_f_pandas["MO_RR"].resample("A").apply(very_sum)

    # creating the dictionary layer for the anual data in this dictionary
    anual_data = {
            "Y_RR" : Y_RR
            }

    # creating the dictionary layer for the montly data in this dictionary
    montly_data = {
            "MO_RR"    
            }

    # creating the dictionary layer for every station. Everystation has montly and anual data
    station = {
            "montly_data" : montly_data,
            "anual_data" : anual_data
            }

    station_data_dictionary["station_data"][station_id] = station
```

Note that you don't need statements like `i = 0` before a `for` loop as the loop initialises the variable for you.

Also the `"station_data"` layer of the dictionary seems superfluous as it is the only key at that layer, but you had it in your required output so I left it in.

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like this is the answer! 
My problem was, that I either build the entire dictionary out or in the loop. But I didn't thought of splitting it. Yes the "station_data" layer of the dictionary seems superfluous at the moment, but I have to ad a "key" layer on the same level. Thank you for leaving it XD . And thank you for the hint with the loop. Will it also work with a "j" in a loop?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure, any variable name works, so you can pick whatever makes most sense in context. `i` is a common choice for the general case.

Comment: Ah oky, thank you. I once build a loop in a loop. There I calld the variable from the second loop j. Thats why I was curious. 
I didn't know the line "station_data_dictionary["station_data"][station_id] = station". Do I have to do this after variable keys in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, `j` is a natural choice for an inner loop when the outer one is `i`. I'm not sure what you mean by "this" in "do this after variable keys," but the syntax `d[station_id] = val` adds a new entry to the dictionary `d`, with the key taken from the value of the variable `station_id`.

Comment: Oky thank you for your explanation. I don't think, I understand dictionaries well enough, to be able to build them with out peeking in this code. I don't have it in my blood yet ;) . But it is fine. I love recycling anyway and I probably look for other examples in the internet, too. Are dictionaries important?

Answer (score 1):

Try this below.
Also, if you need your dictionary to remain ordered in the same way you added them, you'll have to use an OrderedDict from collections package.

Therefore, when you print the dictionary or loop through its data, you'll loop in the same order you've added them in the code below.

Obs: I'm assuming station_data_files_pandas is a list, not a dictionary, that's why I've altered the for loop "signature" to use the enhanced for.
If I'm wrong and this variable is in fact a dictionary, and each integer of the for loop is a key of this dictionary, you could also loop through the items like this:

```py
for k, v in station_data_files_pandas.items():
    # now k carries the integer you were using before.
    # and v carries station_data_f_pandas
```

#### Code correction

```py
import collections

station_data_dictionary=collections.OrderedDict()

#for i in range(len(station_data_files_pandas)):  # range(0, 299)
  # using the enhanced for loop
  for station_data_f_pandas in station_data_files_pandas:  # range(0, 299) 

    # This is not needed anymore    
    # station_data_f_pandas = station_data_files_pandas[i]

    # station_id = str(int(station_data_f_pandas["STATIONS_ID"][0]))
    # You could directly convert to string
    station_id = str(int(station_data_f_pandas["STATIONS_ID"][0]))

    Y_RR = station_data_f_pandas["MO_RR"].resample("A").apply(very_sum)
    MO_RR = # something goes here


    # creating the dictionary layer for the anual data in this dictionary
    anual_data = {
            "Y_RR" : Y_RR
            }

    # creating the dictionary layer for the montly data in this dictionary
    montly_data = {
            # "MO_RR"
            # You can't have just a key to your dictionary, you need to assign a value to it.

            "MO_RR": MO_RR             
            }

    # creating the dictionary layer for every station. Everystation has montly and anual data
    station = {
            "montly_data" : montly_data,
            "anual_data" : anual_data
            }

    # creating the dictionary layer where the staiondata can get called by station id

    station_data_dic = {
            station_id : station
            }


    # creating the final layer of the dictionary
    #station_data_dictionary = {
    #       "station_data": station_data_dic
    #        }

    # Why use {"apparently_useless_id_layer": {"actual_id_info": "data"}}
    # instead of {"actual_info_id": "data"} ?
    station_data_dictionary[station_id] = station
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as well! I think the most crutial things were, that I didn't build my main dictionary outside the loop and that I didn't had this line: "station_data_dictionary[f"station_data_{i}"] = station_data_dic". Also thank you for your hint it the coments. This is very useful!